# Extracting a subsection from a String in java

Tags: regex

I have one huge string with the form:

MarkerBeg 1

...
...

MarkerEnd 1

MarkerBeg 2

...

MarkerEnd 2

I have this information in a string and want to extract the String between each markers(...), is there any way to do this using regex or simple strings methods looking for each marker.

Regards,

Comment: Not really an answer, just a hint. Have you seen: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html
More, can you give us an actual example of a string to parse? Thanks

Comment: Can markers be nested? Marker names repeated?

Comment: Markers are not nested, and the Marker names are the same, the identifier are the ones that changes. i.e. MarkerBeg Hello\n ... MarkerEnd Hello\n MarkerBeg Goodbye\n ... MarkerEnd GoodBye\n

Answer (score 0):

[Edited because question became clearer]

Here's the problem as I understand it:
You have a long string with some blocks of text in it delimited by "MarkerBeg [identifier]" and "MarkerEnd [identifier]". Not all the text in the string is inside one of these blocks, and the blocks cannot be nested. The identifiers can be some arbitrary string (here I'm assuming that they only contain characters in the `\w` class: letters, numbers, and underscores). You need to extract both the identifiers and the strings inside the blocks.

Here's some code that will do what you want:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Hello {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "MarkerBeg 1\n some text\nMarkerEnd 1\nxxx\nMarkerBeg 2\nhi there :) \nMarkerEnd 2\nxyz\nMarkerBeg hello\nzgfds\nMarkerEnd hello";
        System.out.println("source string:\n" + s);
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("MarkerBeg\\s+(\\w+)\\s+(.*)\\s+MarkerEnd\\s+\\1");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
        System.out.println("\nextracted:");
        while (m.find()) {
            String ident = m.group(1);
            String string = m.group(2);
            System.out.println(ident + ": " + string);
        }
    }
}
```

This prints out:

```
source string:
MarkerBeg 1
 some text
MarkerEnd 1
xxx
MarkerBeg 2
hi there :) 
MarkerEnd 2
xyz
MarkerBeg hello
zgfds
MarkerEnd hello

extracted:
1: some text
2: hi there :) 
hello: zgfds
```

The regex works as follows:
regex: `"MarkerBeg\s+(\w+)\s+(.*)\s+MarkerEnd\s+\1"` (backslashes are escaped in original code)
`MarkerBeg`: taken literally
`\s+`: one or more whitespace characters
`(w+)`: one or more letter, number, or underscore characters, placed in a capturing group to extract later (your identifier)
`\s+`: as above
`(.*)`: zero or more characters, placed in a capturing group (the contents of your text block)
`\s+`: as above
`MarkerEnd`: taken literally
`\s+`: as above
`\1`: the contents of the first capturing group (i.e. your identifier)

Then in the loop, I use `m.group(1)` and `m.group(2)` to get the contents of the first and second capturing groups.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition near index 17
(Marker.+? \d+\n*){Hello,Bye}
                          ^

Comment: In this case, what can I do if the identifiers (1,2) are string variables

Comment: Current format does not assure to have two consecutive markers this means markerBeg 1\n... ...\nMarkerEnd "Dummy text" MarkerBeg token\n ... ...\nMarkerEnd token

Comment: @Juan - {1,2} in that regex doesn't refer to the characters '1' and '2', but the number of repetitions (since you have just "MarkerBeg" at the beginning of the string and just "MarkerEnd" at the end of the string). Are you going to have text in between the end of one "Marker" block and the beginning of the next one? If so, the code I wrote won't work.

Comment: Why do you have different identifiers if your text blocks can't be nested? Are you going to use the identifiers for anything?

Comment: I have different identifiers because maybe i need to look in the last block, and somethime in 5th block i need to extract the correct text